# Utilizar el resultado de un servicio angular

Tags: php, symfony, angular6

Estoy trabajando en al Backend con Symfony y el Frontend con angular y se me esta presentando lo siguiente. Tengo una clase afiliado y otra beneficiario, el beneficiario depende de un afiliado previamente ya creado, por esto, tiene una llave foranea hacia el afiliado. En el Frontend cuando voy a registrar a un nuevo beneficiario, utilizo una función del servicio de afiliado para buscar dicho afiliado. Cuando hace la busqueda trae dicho afiliado y rellena algunos campos del formulario. Después llamo la funcion crear del servicio de beneficiario. Cuando creo el beneficiario no esta recogiendo el parametro que necesito del servicio de afiliado. Aqui esta el servicio de afiliado:

```
searchAfiliado(token, cedula){
    let params = "authorization="+token;
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

    return this._http.post(this.url+'/afiliado/search/'+cedula, params, {headers: headers})
                .pipe(
                 map(res => res.json())
                );
}
```

Y asi queda mi componente de beneficiario:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { AfiliadoService } from '../services/afiliado.service';
import { BeneficiarioService } from  '../services/beneficiario.service';
import { Afiliado } from '../models/afiliado';
import { Beneficiario } from '../models/beneficiario';

@Component({
selector: 'beneficiario-new',
templateUrl: '../views/beneficiario.new.html',
providers: [UserService, AfiliadoService, BeneficiarioService]})
export class BeneficiarioNewComponent implements OnInit {

public title: string;
public n_bene;
public identida_usuario;
public token;
public afiliado: Afiliado;
public info_afiliado;
public searchA;
public beneficiario: Beneficiario;
public status;

constructor(
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _afiliadoService: AfiliadoService,
    private _beneficiarioService: BeneficiarioService,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router
) {
    this.title = 'Registrar beneficiarios auxilio economico',
    this.identida_usuario = this._userService.getIdentida_usuario();
    this.token = this._userService.getToken();
    this.n_bene = 1;
}

ngOnInit(){
    console.log('componente de beneficiario cargado')
    if (this.identida_usuario == null && !this.identida_usuario.sub) {
        this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    }else{
        this.beneficiario = new Beneficiario(1, 1, '', 1, ''),
         this.afiliado = new Afiliado(1, 1, "", "", "", "", "", "", 1, "", 1, "",
                                     1, 1, 1, "", 1, "", 1, 1, 1, "", 1, "", "", 1,
                                     "", "", 1, 1, 1)
    }
}

search(){
    console.log(this.searchA);
    this._afiliadoService.searchAfiliado(this.token, this.searchA).subscribe(
        response => {
            //this.afiliado = response.data;
            if (response.status != 'success') {                 
                this.status = 'error';
            }else{
                this.afiliado = response.data;
                console.log(this.afiliado)
                //this._router.navigate(['/new-beneficiario'])
            }
        },
        error => {
            console.log(<any>error)
        }
    );
}

onSubmit(){
console.log(this.beneficiario);

this._beneficiarioService.create(this.token, this.beneficiario).subscribe(
    response => {
        if(response.status != 'success'){
            this.status = 'error';
        }else{
            this.beneficiario = response.data;
            // vaciar formulario
            this.beneficiario = new Beneficiario(1, 1, '', 1, '');
            console.log(this.beneficiario);
            this.n_bene = this.n_bene + 1;
            console.log(this.n_bene);
            console.log(this.afiliado);
            if(this.n_bene <= 3){
                this._router.navigate(['/new-beneficiario']);
            }else{
                this._router.navigate(['/new-beneseguro']);
                }
            }
        },
        error => {
            console.log(<any>error)
        }       
    );
}
}
```

Y por ultimo, en la vista, trato de capturar el id del afiliado consultado, pero no he podido capturar ese valor.

```
<div class="row">
    <h2 class="col-md-6  col-md-offset-4">{{title}}</h2>
    <h3 class="col-md-6  col-md-offset-4">Beneficiario No. {{n_bene}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="form-group"></div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body card-block">
        <div class="alert alert-success" *ngIf="status == 'success'">
            Beneficiario creado correctamente!
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="status == 'error'">
            ¡Lo sentimos... Hubo algun error!
        </div>
        <hr>
        <form class="form-horizontal" #beneficiarioNewForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <form role="search">
                <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchA" placeholder="Cedula o codigo militar..." [(ngModel)]="searchA" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-success" (click)="search();">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="afiliado">
                    <div class="panel panel-default afiliado-data">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h2>{{afiliado.ape1 + ' ' + afiliado.ape2 + ' ' + afiliado.nom1}}</h2>
                            <hr>
                            <h3 class="panel-cedula">
                                Cedula afiliado: <strong>{{afiliado.cedula}}</strong>
                            </h3>
                            <h3 class="panel-codmil">
                                Codigo militar: <strong>{{afiliado.codmil}}</strong>
                            </h3>
                            <h3 class="panel-codmil">
                                id afiliado: <strong>{{afiliado.id}}</strong>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_afiliado" #id_afiliado="ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "beneficiario.id_afiliado" value="afiliado.id">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
                    <label for="text-input" class="form-control-label">Beneficiario</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre_benef" #nombre_benef = "ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "beneficiario.nombre_benef"  placeholder="Nombre del beneficiario" required>
                    <span *ngIf="!nombre_benef.valid && nombre_benef.touched">Nombre invalido!</span>                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
                    <label for="select" class="form-control-label">Parentesco</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                    <select name="parentesco" #id_parentesco = "ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "beneficiario.id_parentesco" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">Hermano</option>
                    <option value="2">Hijo(a)</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-1">
                    <label for="select" class="form-control-label">Edad</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="edad_bene" #edad = "ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "beneficiario.edad" placeholder="edad" required>
                    <span *ngIf="!edad.valid && edad.touched">Edad invalida!</span> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">                
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-2">                       
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-1">                       
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
                    <input type="submit" value="Registrar beneficiario" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" [disabled]="!beneficiarioNewForm.form.valid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>            
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me surgen varias dudas: en el servicio ¿de qué clase es la propiedad `_http`? ¿Por qué usas una llamada POST en lugar de GET? ¿Qué error te sale en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Por lo demás, es una buena primera pregunta, bienvenido a SOes!

Comment: _htpp es una propiedad privada tipo Http que importo de @angular/http. Uso una llamada post por que en el controlador del back envió un parámetro de búsqueda. En la consola no me sale ningún error, solo que no se como extraer tomar un valor que necesito de la salida del servicio de búsqueda.

Comment: Deberías usar la clase HttpClient en lugar de Http, es lo recomendado desde angular 5